# Using datetime to compare with dates in Django

Tags: django, datetime, view, models, datefield

I have a question in Django on how you can compare dates to solve some solutions. For example I have a datefield in my models.py Like below.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

What I want to be able to do is ask if the is a way to compare a datetime.now with a DateTimeField. For example, if I had a list of payment dates and I wanted to compare with datetime now. Thhe payment_date's that are late with their payments are shown in owing. Otherwise, it the value is zero.

Here is my views to show whats going on. I have tried so far but I get a 0 value for payment_date's which are later than the payment date.

Edit here is my latest views. Funny thing is that I seem to be getting the owing = invoice_gross for all results - unlike before when I was getting all 0s. So it is still not working properly.

```
@login_required
def homepage(request):
    invoices_list = Invoice.objects.all()
    invoice_name = invoices_list[0].client_contract_number.client_number.name
    invoice_gross = invoices_list[0].invoice_gross
    payment_date = invoices_list[0].payment_date
    if payment_date <= datetime.now():
        owing = invoice_gross
        if payment_date > datetime.now():
            owing = 0
    return render_to_response(('index.html', locals()), {'invoices_list': invoices_list ,'invoice_name':invoice_name, 'invoice_gross':invoice_gross,'payment_date':payment_date,'owing':owing}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Oh and my table is basically doing something like this.

```
ID  Owing
1   100   (All the same value)
2   100
3   100
.   .
.   .
.   .
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the problem is in the line

```
if datetime.now() == payment_date:
```

That will literally see if the `payment_date` is *right now*. I think you want to see if now is greater than or equal to the `payment_date`, in which case you should use

```
if datetime.now() >= payment_date:
```

You can also just filter the invoices when you query the database:

```
invoices_list = Invoice.objects.filter(payment_date__lte=datetime.now())
```

## Update

Your code is wrong because you have mutually exclusive conditionals. Look:

```
if payment_date <= datetime.now():
    owing = invoice_gross
    if payment_date > datetime.now():
        owing = 0
```

That first checks to see if `payment_date` is before now. Then it sets `owing` to `invoice_gross`. *Then*, *in the same conditional*, it checks to see if `payment_date` is after now. But that can't be! You are only in this block of code if `payment_date` is *before* now!

I think you have an indentation error, and want this instead:

```
if payment_date <= datetime.now():
    owing = invoice_gross
if payment_date > datetime.now():
    owing = 0
```

Which, of course, is the same as:

```
if payment_date <= datetime.now():
    owing = invoice_gross
else:
    owing = 0
```

Comment: if I change "if datetime.now >= payment_date:" I get this error 
can't compare datetime.date to builtin_function_or_method

Comment: `datetime.now` is a function, call it by `datetime.now()`

Comment: Back on my computer. It is still not working properly. Look at the latest code.

Comment: The funny indent error has stopped appearing. Only problem is I still have the same problem. I have a table where in one column displays invoice number. The other displays owing payments. Each invoice number correspond to that owing. When there is least one owing = invoice_gross, ALL of the rows in that column displays the same owing value. I am not sure why it is doing this.

Comment: @Shehzad009: Well, you're only checking the payment date of the *first* invoice, and setting `owing` to that value. Is that what you want?

Comment: @mipadi One invoice has one payment_date. I need to check for all payment_date. If one payment_date that is overdue, their value is the same as invoice gross. If one payment_date is not overdue the value is zero. Hope that helps

Answer (score 11):

Use `datetime.now()` (notice the parens). Other than that, remember that the field will *always* be a `datetime` object. Also, (I guess that) you should check only the *date* of the *datetime* to match the current date (or else it will only match that specific second). For that you have to check if `payment_date.date() == date.today()` (where `date` is `datetime.date`)

This also means that you can filter like this: `Invoice.objects.filter(payment_date__lte=datetime.now())`.

*`__lte`, `__gte`, `__lt`, `__gt` are used for `<=`, `>=`, `<` and `>`*

Answer (score 1):

Thank to Mushahid Khan
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37596662/12575117

(Short Code)
You can use this one:

```
from django.utils.timezone import datetime
```