# DatetimeField filter after a given date

Tags: python, django, datetime, filter, django-queryset

Is it possible to filter over a DateTimeField to get all objects who have a DateTimeField later to the given date ? 
For instance :

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

in a view :

```
given_date = someDateTime
new_items = MyObject.objects.filter(updated_date__after = given_date)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`__gt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt) in a double underscore notation:

```
new_items = MyObject.objects.filter(updated_date__gt=given_date)
```

Relevant threads:

- [Django database query: How to filter objects by date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range)
- [Django query datetime for objects older than 5 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345147/django-query-datetime-for-objects-older-than-5-hours)
- [Using datetime to compare with dates in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606207/using-datetime-to-compare-with-dates-in-django)